# Force flyway db migrations to have test data on every new migration

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, database-migration, flyway

I am using flyway DB migrations. Recently I started testing my migrations with test data for each migration I made. For example db/migrations has all the migration scripts starting with V001__create_table1.sql, V002__create_table2.sql... db/migrations/afterEachMigrate has all the testing data starting with V001.1__insert_test_data_in_table1.sql, V002.1__insert_test_data_in_table2.sql.

I am testing these scripts like below.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import(FlywayCallback::class)
class DatabaseMigrationScriptIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var strategy: FlywayMigrationConfig

  private val log = LogFactory.getLog(javaClass)

  @BeforeEach
  fun setUp() {
    strategy.cleanMigrateStrategy()
  }

  @Test
  fun successfullyRunsMigrationsWithTestingData() {
    val configureFlyway = flywaySetup()
    val runMigrations = configureFlyway.migrate()
    Assertions.assertThat(runMigrations.migrationsExecuted)
  }

  private fun flywaySetup(): Flyway {
    return Flyway.configure()
      .dataSource("jdbc:tc:mysql://localhost:3306", "test", "test")
      .locations("classpath:db/migration", "classpath:db/migration/afterEachMigrate")
      .callbacks(FlywayCallback())
      .load()
  }
```

What I want to do now is force test data on every new migration.
For example if I add  V003__alter_table_1.sql, the test should try to look for (V003.1__alter_test_data) test data to insert new values.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. What do you mean "the test should try to look for"? What does look mean in this context?